# Is it possible to convert a QTabBar inside the QTabWidget into a QComboBox?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

Is it possible to convert a QTabBar inside the QTabWidget into a QComboBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might somehow be possible by overwriting `QTabWidget`, but I think the much cleaner, faster and easier solution would be to combine `QComboBox` and `QStackedWidget` to a new widget.

Comment: ya that's what i think too ..... but is there any direct way of doing that? Seems like none .... right?